# Best choice for private/home network TLD? Overlap with mDNS?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, mdns

I'm trying to make my home network settings sane and I noticed I have a mix of TLDs with .local and .localdomain (the latter is the default of my Ubiquiti Security Gateway). I understand that .local is the TLD for mDNS but I'm not finding results online that clarify if I should ignore that and set my DNS's TLD to something different or if it's ok to also make it .local or if that will hose everything.

The logical extension to this question is, what is a good setting for my home TLD? I've seen that there's a recent RFC saying the current best practice is home.arpa. It seems like the pragmatic answer is, I can pick anything I like but it may conflict with something official someday and then I'll have problems.

Notes:

- My home network is mixed clients: Mac laptops and other Apple products like iPhones/iPads and Apple TV, Windows clients, IoT devices, etc.
- I'm not using the optional dnsmasq as a DHCP server on the USG. (Anyone knows if that's preferred? I can't find doc on why I'd choose that versus the default.)

(I am a software engineer but not a network engineer. Assume I know enough to be dangerous. :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that there are only two acceptable options: 1) `.home.arpa` or another explicitly reserved domain; 2) your own domain registered in the DNS or its subdomain. Anything else is bad practice.

Fake TLDs can someday be added to the real IANA TLD list. Fake second-level domains can also someday turn into real domains.

- This recently occured with `.dev`, which was apparently popular for local website development.
- "Unused" IP addresses can also one day be in actual use, as happened with 1.1.1.1 (often a common placeholder address but now a real Internet address).
- The only ways to ensure this won't happen are either to use a domain registered to you personally (buy one), or a domain reserved for "private" use (such as home.arpa).

Some domains have special treatment in code:

- Some resolvers always use mDNS for names under `.local` and never query it using regular unicast DNS. There is a mechanism for detecting unicast .local usage but not all resolvers implement it.
- Resolvers are [forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7686) from using any form of DNS for names under the `.onion` TLD, making it purely Tor's territory.
- Many resolvers short-circuit queries for `localhost.` by always responding with the same 127.0.0.1 and [::1] addresses (it's a security issue if they don't). This does not generally apply to subdomains under `.localhost` though.

Some domains have special treatment in web browsers:

- The same `.dev` which turned into a TLD also got added to web browsers' "HSTS preload" lists, with the result that browsers started *requiring* HTTPS with a recognized certificate for any domain under that TLD.

DNSSEC-validating resolvers will only allow you to override suffixes for which the parent zone has an existing 'insecure' delegation without DS records:

- There are NS *and* DS records at `dev.`, so a validating resolver will require any responses for its subdomains to have correct RRSIGs and will not accept your 'fake' responses.
- There are neither NS nor DS records at `home.`, and a validating resolver will recognize this as an "authenticated denial of existence" and will not accept any responses for subdomains underneath.
- There are only NS records at `home.arpa.` but no DS records, so your home DNS server can freely generate 'fake' responses for its subdomains.

Comment: But will OP's MacOS devices use home.arpa as a search domain?  I'm not sure that works.  See my related question https://superuser.com/questions/1721039/can-macos-use-home-arpa-as-a-dns-search-suffix-mine-is-configured-but-macos-see