# Can MacOS use home.arpa as a DNS search suffix? Mine is configured but MacOS seems to ignores it

Tags: networking, mac, dns

My home DNS domain is `home.arpa`, and my Mac cannot resolve simple DNS hostnames (without domain), e.g. `pc`.  However, it will resolve the fqdn just fine, e.g. `pc.home.arpa`.  The domain `home.arpa` is being handed out by the DHCP server, I can see it in my Mac's network settings, and I can see it in `resolv.conf`, and I can see it the output of `scutil --dns`.

I've used DNS suffixes before, they've always worked.  So, I'm led to wonder: does MacOS ignore `home.arpa` search suffix, and can anything be done to change that behaviour?

Comment: Note, MacOS is 10.15.7.  I've Googled for this issue, didn't find much at all, except for one conversation that where someone had excact same problem, but no solution.

Comment: so your issue is specifically that search domain configuration doesn't appear to be working? do you have a DNS server or are you attempting this using bonjour/avahi/zero-conf?

Comment: @FrankThomas DNS server, and yeah only that domain, and only MacOS.  Works fine from Windows PC on same network, also on DHCP.

Comment: I would run tcpdump and check whether it is going to the tld .arpa. ns servers to resolve home.arpa., which it won't since those servers know nothing about your system. The .apra. domain is normally used for reverse resolution of IPv4 & IPv6 addresses, so I have no idea why you are using it. I think you are using that domain incorrectly.

Comment: home.arpa was reserved by the IETF, and set up the authoritative servers to blackhole requests for it, so it should be fine as long as there is a local DNS server that hosts your instance of the zone. That said, I would avoid using it, since .arpa is a weird case and not all vendors are likely implement functions surrounding it correctly. just feels like asking for trouble. all i can advise is to confirm you are resolving against the correct server, and that your search domain configuration is correct.

Comment: Yep, search domain is being handed out by the DHCP server, and works on Windows, and not on MacOS.

Comment: This domain seems to be used by NetBIOS rather than DNS. Is NetBIOS enabled (it is usually by default)?

Comment: Is NetBIOS enabled?

Comment: @harrymc can you elaborate when you say ‘seems to be used by NetBIOS’?

Comment: This was in one post that I have seen. You could try it and see if it's true.

Comment: @harrymc doesn't make a lot of sense, but confirming NetBIOS hasn't been disabled.  Bear in mind, other search domains work correctly.  Can you link to that post?

Answer (score 1):

`home.arpa` is not recognized in OSX Monterey. Even forcing the domain search with configs do not work.

Just pick something else.

Comment: Indeed.  Shame Apple decided to break the only truly RFC-compliant local domain (apart from purchased public domains as you might use in a corporate).  Annoying that they honour it for FQDN requests, which kinda makes them RFC-compliant, but they dump it from search domain processing, which makes them irritating.

Answer (score 0):

`home.arpa` appears to work for me on macOS Ventura 13.2.1. Using a Ubiquiti Unifi Dream Machine Pro.

```
❯ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : home.arpa
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.1.1
  if_index : 13 (en7)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200
...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1178402)

Comment: Same as the question - I can see it in scutil output.